# Need regex to remove unnecessary strings in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have big css file and need regex(Notepad++) to get only elements and css selectors found by specific css value. In following example I need to get element and selector by value `123456`

```
header #objectnav nav a {
  border-right: solid 1px #c0c0c0;
  border-left: solid 1px #f4f9ff;
  color: #123456;
}

a:hover {
  color: #654321;
}

#hints .hint {
  background-color: #f4f9ff;
  border: 1px solid #e0f0ff;
  color: #123456;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

on exit I expect following

```
header #objectnav nav a
color

#hints .hint
color
```

or, if possible

```
header #objectnav nav a^color
#hints .hint^color
```

Comment: What regexes have you tried so far? SO is not just an answer machine.

Comment: And which part are you battling with?

Comment: @Benno Zeeman, the problem is that i'm not strong in regex at all. I was trying different combinations, but without any success and I'm ashamed to post them.

Comment: Don't be ashamed, post them! ;)

Comment: @Benno Zeeman, no-no-no cat)) better I find out by myself))

Answer (score 1):

I did this just for the challenge:

The following regex will find all the rules containing the text `123456` as a value:

```
[^{}\s][^{}]*\{[^}]*?[-\w]+\s*:[^;}]*?123456[^}]*\}
```

But that's just a basic regex. The more challenging part is that I wondered if it's possible to generate a report such as the one you asked for using nothing but Notepad++. It turns out it's possible.

Replace the following pattern:

```
\s*([^{}]+?)\s*\{[^}]*?(?(?=([-\w]+)\s*:[^;}]*?123456)[^}]*|[^}])*\}\s*
```

With the following replacement string:

```
(?2$1^$2:)
```

Or this one depending on the output you prefer:

```
(?2$1\r\n$2\r\n\r\n:)
```

I didn't test it extensively but it works for the test cases you provided.